# Azure Data Factory Studio not opening

Tags: azure-data-factory

When I am trying to open ADF portal, it's giving this error.
[image: adf.azure.com opening error]

After giving https, the error is below.
[image: https://adf.azure.com error]

After doing nslookup I got this-

[image: nslookup result]

It seems, private link has been configured for ADF.
This are the Private DNS Zone setup. Can you see any discrepancies here?
[image: privatelink.adf.azure.com]

[image: privatelink.datafactory.azure.net]

The asked Data Factory instance have Private endpoint enabled.
[image: Network]

Can anyone find any problem here? If yes please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see 404 or **adf.azure.com** in the browser, it usually means you have some client-side issue. Further follow the troubleshooting steps.

To troubleshoot further, open Command Prompt and type `nslookup dpnortheurope.svc.datafactory.azure.com`. A normal response should look like below:

[image]

- If you see a normal Domain Name Service (DNS) response, contact your local IT support to check the firewall settings. Be sure HTTPS connections to this host name are not blocked. If the issue persists, file a support ticket with ADF providing the Activity ID from the error message.
- An DNS response differing from the normal response above might also mean a problem exists with your DNS server when resolving the DNS name. Changing your DNS server (for example, to Google DNS 8.8.8.8) could workaround the issue in that case.
- If the issue persists, you could further try nslookup datafactory.azure.com and nslookup azure.com to see at which level your DNS resolution is failed and submit all information to your local IT support or your ISP for troubleshooting. If they believe the issue is still at Microsoft side, file a support ticket with the Activity ID from the error message.

[image]

Source: [Troubleshoot Azure Data Factory Studio Issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-ux-troubleshoot-guide?tabs=edge#connection-failed-error-in-azure-data-factory-studio)